# Javascript function execution time increases 10x after some time

Tags: javascript, performance, memory-management, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory

I have somewhat expensive task that needs to be executed a few times by my users. The task uses the [ImageTracer](https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs) library. This task starts off taking about 1 second, but usually after executing a few times (2-10) the task suddenly takes 20+ seconds, even though none of the input arguments are different. Sometimes I never hit this increase, and sometimes it takes much longer to hit.

Other libraries I am using:

- Vue.js
- Fabric.js

My first guess was that this is some sort of memory issue, so I went to chrome dev tools and captured the heap size. You can [download the profile here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8e521a391f27c8295266923d52cc291b20200724173326/9ffc36) and here is a screenshot:

[image: dev tools performance tab]

You can clearly see that the last 2 task executions took significantly longer than the first couple. I am not very experienced with js and the chrome dev tools, but that doesn't seem like a memory leak to me. The heap size is not significantly larger at the end than at the beginning (both around 8mb). Please correct me if I am wrong and this does indicate a memory leak.

However those memory spikes seem like they might be an issue (or maybe a symptom of some other issue). Zooming in you can see an immediate jump from 15mb to 80mb and then back down to 15mb only 20ms later. Strangly the jump seems to coincide with a Major GC.

[image]

I am not sure if this is a problem and if it is how to further debug it.

I tried whittling the code down to a small self contained reproducible example, but as I got the code smaller and smaller the error became more and more rare to trigger, eventually disappearing. To me this also indicated I am dealing with some sort of memory issue.

I have made a [somewhat simplified version that does show my issue however](https://memory-error.onrender.com/).

For me this problem is only reproducible in Chrome (also tested in Safari and Firefox). I am using a 2018 MacBook Pro with 16GB of memory and running Catalina.

My Questions:

- Can anyone see an obvious issue in the profile posted above?
- Is this most likely a memory bug and if so what are the next steps to continue debugging?
- Are there any workarounds that would enable me to essentially reload or reset the offending js library (since the first couple of task executions always seem to go smoothly.

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome's GC so try Chrome Canary or a [much] older portable Chrome/ium. P.S. The profile file at the link is basically empty.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have updated the link in the question to another site that will hopefully work better: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8e521a391f27c8295266923d52cc291b20200724173326/9ffc36

Comment: Can you edit the function to add `console.time()` to each line to figure out which lines is slowing down?

Comment: @Trevor yes I have done that. The slow call is the call into the ImageTracer library, here is the line: https://github.com/jminardi/memory-example/blob/master/index.html#L744-L748 and within that library the slow call seems to be `blur`: https://github.com/jankovicsandras/imagetracerjs/blob/master/imagetracer_v1.2.6.js#L1043